# TYPO3 realrul broken? L=../ equal L=0

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, realurl

I have a TYPO3 v8.7 (ELTS) and use realurl. Now I have found that in addition to the parameters L=0 and L=1, L=../ also leads to a page being called up. L=../ remains in the web address in the browser and shows me the page from L=0. How can I prevent this from redirecting to a 404 page of my choice? Where do I have to start in the realurl configuration?

Comment: So, you have problems with other `L` parameters than the integers 0 and 1?

Comment: For incomprehensible reasons, ../ and other things are added to the L parameter. L(0-1) brought no success.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that only a given range of parameter values will actually make it to the page rendering process.

Take a look at https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/8.7/en-us/Setup/Config/Index.html#linkvars

to get some additional information about configuration options for linkVars.

Comment: That has had no effect. Cache was then cleared.